# Compress chaindata folder

Tags: blockchain

Hey I want to transfer the blockchain to a new computer, however my usb only has 32GB. Could I use gzip on the chaindata folder, or will this corrupt it?

Comment: use a checksum when you move your data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compression will not alter the content of the files. Go ahead.